# R loop trough different lists

Tags: r, list, loops

I work in R and have List A and List B, in which list A <<< B. 
Both lists share the value of the entry of one column (chr.).
I want to add a new column to list B based on entry of list A.
I.e in list B, look at column xy for any shared values with list A at column zk, add a new column to list B with the values of list A of column p.

```
for(i in range(1:length(B[[y]]))){for(j in range(1:length(A[[x]]))){if(A[[x]] == B[[y]]){mutate(B, newvalue = A[[z))}}}
```

Comment: Can you please provide minimal reproducible sample data and matching expected output? That way it will be much easier for us to help because it gives us something to work with. At the moment your code is not reproducible because we have no idea how `A` and `B` look like.

Comment: If you need help with the reproducible example, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I believe that you need the `merge` function.

Answer (score 0):

As @G5W indicated you can use `merge` function. At first you should convert your lists into the data frames then `merge`. After it you can convert the resulting data frame back into list.

Basically there is no need to implement the algorithm yourself using for loops. It is already done in base R.
Please see the code below:

```
l1 <- list(x = 3:7, y = letters[3:7])
l2 <- list(x = 1:10, z = letters[1:10])
df1 <- as.data.frame(l1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- as.data.frame(l2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df_m <- merge(df1, df2)
l_m <- as.list(df_m)
l_m
```

Output:

```
$`x`
[1] 3 4 5 6 7

$y
[1] "c" "d" "e" "f" "g"

$z
[1] "c" "d" "e" "f" "g"
```